# How to disable ETag headers in Tomcat 9?

Tags: tomcat9, etags

How to disable ETag headers in Tomcat 9 ? It will be helpful if provided with details/examples etc.

Need to remove etags as this is reported as vulnerability in security scan . Tried different solutions on the net, but none worked.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: and why would you want this?

Comment: Need to remove etags as this is reported as vulnerability in security scan . Tried different solutions on the net, but none worked.

Comment: @sagar, add in the question the solutions you try.

Comment: I  tried https://serverfault.com/questions/232763/how-to-disable-etag-headers-in-tomcat, but not sure where to place java code .